# If a bijection of a plane to it self takes a rectangle to a rectangle then it takes a square to a square

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Let $f$ be a bijection of a plane to it self which takes rectangle to a rectangle.
>
> Prove it takes square to a square.

My idea was to  put whole thing in the coordinate system...?

*This is a problem from international math olympiad longlist 1987 and it does not assumes that preseves area.*

Comment: Scaling is a bijection that takes a rectangle to a rectangle, but a square only becomes a rectangle. Do you want additional conditions like preserve area?

Comment: For example $f(x,y) = (x,2y)$ scales it in the y-direction by 2.

Comment: So, you mean this ILL problem is false? @CalvinLin

Comment: Aqua, no I'm wrong. Scaling doesn't map a tilted rectangle into a rectangle (e.g. angles are not preserved)

Answer (score 2):

Such an $f$ maps lines $\ell$ to lines and parallel lines $\ell$, $\ell'$ to parallel lines.

*Proof.* Given two parallel lines $\ell$, $\ell'$ at distance $d$ you can inscribe a sequence of adjacent rectangles $R_i$ into the infinite strip the two lines form. These $R_i$ will be mapped to adjacent rectangles (of maybe different lengths). The $f(R_i)$ therefore again form an infinite strip, bounded by  two parallel lines. These lines are nothing else but  $f(\ell)$, $f(\ell')$.

Such a map $f$ (even non-area-preserving) maps squares to squares.

*Proof.* Consider a square $Q$ and split it into four congruent quarters by drawing symmetry lines $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$. The image $R:=f(Q)$ will be a rectangle that is divided into four smaller rectangles by the images   $f(\ell_1)$, $f(\ell_2)$. These images are parallel to the edges of $R$. Now $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$ intersect the edges of $Q$ in four points which form the vertices of a square $Q'$. The images of these four points are lying on the edges of $R$. They can only be the vertices of a rectangle when $R$ is in fact a square.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the point of this adjacent rectangles in 1 st. proof

Comment: Why do you need a sequence of rectangles? Is it not enough to take just one rectangle defined with $\ell$ and $\ell$'?

Comment: @Aqua: I need that rectangles go into rectangles, hence right angles into right angles, in order to finally prove that infinite lines go into infinite lines.